# db2 remove all non-alphanumeric, including non-printable, and special characters

Tags: db2, special-characters, translate

This may sound like a duplicate, but existing solutions does not work.
I need to remove all non-alphanumerics from a varchar field. I'm using the following but it doesn't work in all cases (it works with diamond questionmark characters):

```
  select TRANSLATE(FIELDNAME, '?',
                 TRANSLATE(FIELDNAME , '', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789')) 
   from TABLENAME
```

What it's doing is the inner translate parse all non-alphanumeric characters, then the outer translate replace them all with a '?'. This seems to work for replacement character�. However, it throws `The second, third or fourth argument of the TRANSLATE scalar function is incorrect.` which is expected according to IBM:

`The TRANSLATE scalar function does not allow replacement of a character by another character which is encoded using a different number of bytes. The second and third arguments of the TRANSLATE scalar function must end with correctly formed characters`.

Is there anyway to get around this?

Edit: @Paul Vernon's solution seems to be working:

```
· 6005308      ??6005308
–6009908       ?6009908
–6011177       ?6011177
��6011183�� ??6011183??
```

Comment: What's your db2 version and platform?  
What's your database codepage?  
Provide some examples of `hex(your_varchar_column)` values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `regexp_replace(c,'[^\w\d]','')`  or `regexp_replace(c,'[^a-zA-Z\d]','')`

E.g.

```
select regexp_replace(c,'[^a-zA-Z\d]','') from table(values('AB_- C$£abc�$123£')) t(c)
```

which returns

```
1
---------
ABCabc123
```

BTW Note that the allowed regular expression patterns are listed on this page [Regular expression control characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64306202/remove-special-characters-and-alphabets-from-a-string-except-number-in-sql-query)

Outside of a set, the following must be preceded with a backslash to be treated as a literal

> `* ? + [ ( ) { } ^ $ | \ . /`

Inside a set, the follow must be preceded with a backslash to be treated as a literal

> Characters that must be quoted to be treated as literals are `[ ] \`
> Characters that might need to be quoted, depending on the context are `- &`

Comment: Looks very simple and it works. Thank you very much. Is there any special case I need to worry about? Just like I thought `translate` would work when it works with diamond and it crashes when it work with different byte data.

Comment: Should be fine for multi-byte data. Not sure about invalid UTF-8 bytes, but it appears to strip those too. BTW I changed the above to use `a-zA-Z` rather than `\w` as that includes `[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\u200c\u200d]` as per here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061533.html

Comment: Cannot understand what they're saying but I tried `values regexp_replace('abc-' || char(10) || char(13) || 'def10.00','[^\w\d]','');` and it prints `abc1013def1000`.