# Remove special characters and alphabets from a string except number in sql query in db2

Tags: sql, db2

Hi I tried using Regex_replace and it is still not working.

select CASE WHEN sbbb <> ' ' THEN regexp_replace(sbbb,'[a-zA-Z _-#]','']
ELSE sbbb
AS ABCDF
from Table where sccc=1;

This is the query which I am using to remove alphabets and specials characters from string and have only numbers. but it doesnot work. Query returns me the complete string with numbers,characters and special characters .What is wrong in the above query

I am working on a sql query. There is a column in database which contains characters,special characters and numbers. I want to only keep the numbers and remove all the special characters and alphabets. How can I do it in query of DB2. If a use PATINDEX it is not working. please help here.

Comment: Duplicate of [db2 remove all non-alphanumeric, including non-printable, and special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54697743/db2-remove-all-non-alphanumeric-including-non-printable-and-special-characters)

Comment: It helps to get your syntax correct when you ask a question. Your `CASE` omits an `END` so will not compile.  Your pattern string includes characters that you must escape with backslash, specifically the underscore and hyphen. You should also edit your question to give the exact colum datatype of the `sbbb` column __and__ its encoding (codepage), along with the Db2-platform (Z/OS, i-series, linux/unix/windows) for your Db2-server.

Answer (score 0):

The allowed regular expression patterns are listed on this page

[Regular expression control characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64306202/remove-special-characters-and-alphabets-from-a-string-except-number-in-sql-query)

Outside of a set, the following must be preceded with a backslash to be treated as a literal

> `* ? + [ ( ) { } ^ $ | \ . /`

Inside a set, the follow must be preceded with a backslash to be treated as a literal

> Characters that must be quoted to be treated as literals are `[ ] \`
> Characters that might need to be quoted, depending on the context are `- &`

So for you, this should work

```
regexp_replace(sbbb,'[a-zA-Z _\-#]','')
```